# IntelliJ IDEA: JS debugger doesn't show properties with getters/setters

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm, getter-setter

When I debug my node-js application in **IntelliJ IDEA** (2020.2 ultimate edition), I can't see the properties with getters (or setters):

[image]

But when I debug the same program in **VS Code** I can see a full list of properties (including them with getters/setters):

[image]

Comment: can you see them if you expand the `__proto__` node?

Comment: @lena; Yes. I can. Thank you. Is there any way to auto-resolve some getters?

Comment: It looks like to be impossible now: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206061009-When-debugging-Javascript-can-I-make-the-debug-window-execute-all-getters-for-an-object-

Comment: please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43050 to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: @lena; Thank you.